# Grabbing all URLs on page to make changes results in huge performance hit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

To make a long story short, I'm making a quick extension for personal use - nothing major. Say we have about 50 URLs that fit what I'm looking for on a page, with maybe 100 URLs in total.. My goal is to convert all of the ones that contain `example.com/xyx` and convert them to `otherexample.com/xyz`. Naturally, here's what I've got:

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', processLinks);
$(document).ready(processLinks);
function processLinks(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace("example.com","otherexample.com");
  });
};
```

But, again, this is hitting performance hard. In my past experiences, I would attempt to grab only links that contain `example.com`, and then make the change. Or, maybe even better, grab and make the conversions only if they're on screen.

I mean, it'd be possible to do something like:

```
$('a.title, a.madeVisible, .md [href*="example.com"]')
```

However, since this is my first attempt and I'm not much further than basic functionality, I'd have no idea how to go about optimizing this to catch links ONLY when necessary and then actually implementing it. Would you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Updated code:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(this.href.match(/example.com/g)){
      this.href = this.href.replace('example.com', 'newexample.com');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if(this.href.match(/example.com/g)){
        this.href = this.href.replace("example.com","otherexample.com");
    }
})
```

That way you only check the link as it's actually being clicked on?

This is untested, so you might need to tweak the script, but the concept should get you where you want to go.

Edit:

Update for your comment, you could use .hover(). .hover() will accept two functions as arguments. One to handle mouseenter and one to handle mouseleave.

So, asuming your markup looks like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/image.png">
    <img src="http://example.come/image.png">
</a>
```

You could do basically the same thing:

```
$(a).hover(function(){
     if(this.href.match(/example.com/g)){
        $(this).data('original-url', this.href) //store original url on the dom node
        this.href = this.href.replace("example.com","otherexample.com");
        $(this).hoverzoom()
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('original-url'));
    }
 }
 );
```

**Double edit:** I suspect your issue is actually with the hoverzoom addon itself. I've added a potential workaround to this code.

Comment: I made a few changes as seen in the main post. I'm still running into the problem that the URL the Hoverzoom plugin is loading is the original, unconverted URL even though both the conversion method and hover plugin activate on mouseover. I'd need a way of converting the URLs BEFORE you click or hover on it, while not doing them all at once. Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is actually in the hoverzoom addon. If you activate hoverzoom with something like $('img').hoverzoom(); or $('hoverzoom-image').hoverzoom(), then you could put `$(this).hoverzoom();` in the function for .hover()

Comment: I think there's actually a combination of problems. What I know right now is that, if I pull and change all the images on page load as in the original code, we get bad performance BUT it works perfectly. If I change it to alter the link on mouseover, we get great performance BUT the image no longer functions with the Hoverzoom plugin. This leads me to suspect that the solution lies somewhere in between... by converting reasonable amounts of links at a time while still being prior to mouseover or click.

Comment: I'm thinking hoverzoom is somehow caching the lightbox links as it goes through when you call `$().hoverzoom();` Try calling it on individual elements as I did in my .hover() example.

Comment: I don't know if that's what you're getting at, but Hoverzoom is actually an entirely separate extension that grabs the URL and puts it into what I would guess to be a small HTML page popup, allowing you to view the image without leaving the page. The only solution I can think of... is there some form of action we can do that converts images as they come on screen? It keeps links manageable in quantity, and might just be early enough to keep Hoverzoom happy.

Comment: I'm aware of what hoverzoom is. What I'm trying to say is at some point in one of your scripts, you are initializing your add-on somehow, `$(foo).hoverzoom()` probably. This call initializes hoverzoom on all the links. Instead of initializing it on all elements, initialize it on each individually inside of the .hover() function.

Comment: I don't understand. These are two Chrome extensions, one of them being mine and the other being Hoverzoom. I don't make any contact between mine and Hoverzoom other than on the page. I don't understand why it sounds like you believe I somehow have control over the behavior of Hoverzoom when it's its own extension.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I thought we were talking about a jquery addon.

Comment: That's what I thought you might've been thinking.. I apologize, it was just a misconception! If you've got any other idea, let me know! Otherwise, I'll probably just mark you as answer and do some investigation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say there are 100 links you want to modify. Each modification triggers `DOMSubtreeModified`, which starts a new loop of 99 links to modify. Long story short, you end up with 100*99*98*97*96*...*1 operation.

Edit: I *may* be wrong there, since you're using `this.href`, which is a property and doesn't actually modify the DOM. But you get the point why `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated. It's basically an invitation to shoot your own foot.

Comment: does subtreemodified count attribute changes? i thought it only fired on new text/element nodes...

Comment: "This is a general event for notification of all changes to the document." http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: I made the change and it no longer uses DOMSubtreeModified. Now, it'll convert the link on mouseover. However, I need to convert the link BEFORE mouseover, but it also can't be all of the URLs at once. No idea how to approach this. Updated code in main post.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just change them on the fly.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = this.href.replace('example.com', 'otherexample.com');
});
```

Comment: I made a few changes, instead of on click it's now on mouseover, and instead of `window.location.href` it's now `this.href`. I'm still running into the problem that the URL the Hoverzoom plugin is loading is the original, unconverted one even though both activate on mouseover. I'd need a way of converting the URLs BEFORE you click or hover on it, while not doing them all at once. Thoughts?

Comment: I would avoid using mouseover, basically my idea is that when a user clicks the link, you stop the browser from doing anything via `e.preventDefault()`, then, you use replace on `this.href` - `this.href` is referring to the anchor tag that was just clicked. Then you can make sure that you're directing the user to the desired domain by that value to window.location.href - which will redirect the browser.